# Issue with Dynamic arraylist

Tags: android, dynamic, arraylist

In my project I used a dynamic array, but the output results in mistake :
my code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < save; i++) {
    a[i] = (double) db.get_a("loc", i);
    b[i] = (double) db.get_b("loc", i);
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        numbers.add(a[i] + b[i]);
    }
    Log.i("LOG", "Array Index #" + i + " = " + numbers.get(i));
}
Log.i("LOG", "Array size #" + numbers.size());
```

in my logcat :

```
11-23 15:35:07.443: I/LOG(1880): Array Index #0 = 7.0
11-23 15:35:07.473: I/LOG(1880): Array Index #1 = 7.0
11-23 15:35:07.535: I/LOG(1880): Array Index #2 = 7.0
11-23 15:35:07.583: I/LOG(1880): Array Index #3 = 7.0
11-23 15:35:07.693: I/LOG(1880): Array Index #4 = 7.0
11-23 15:35:07.763: I/LOG(1880): Array Index #5 = 7.0
11-23 15:35:07.774: I/LOG(1880): Array size #36
```

Comment: How is db.get_a and db.get_b implemented?

Comment: Its not cleat, whats the problem. Can you please elaborate so that users can help here

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you try to do is not what you want.

The code you provided works as follows

`save` seems to be `6`. At first iteration of (`i`, `save`) you get a and b

Then at the (`j`, `6`) iteration you insert 6 times the result in the `numbers`

The code can rewritten to

```
for (int i = 0; i < save; i++) {
    a[i] = (double) db.get_a("loc", i);
    b[i] = (double) db.get_b("loc", i);
    double sum = a[i] + b[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        numbers.add(sum); // Inserting the same value 6 times
        int cal_index = i * 6 + j;
         // Printing all the ArrayList positions
        Log.i("LOG", "* Array Index #" + cal_index + " = " + numbers.get(cal_index));
    }
     // printing the first 6 positions
    Log.i("LOG", "Array Index #" + i + " = " + numbers.get(i));
}
Log.i("LOG", "Array size #" + numbers.size());
```